# If notify and indicate properties exist in one characteristic in Python bleak

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm using bleak to control BLE(bluetooth low energy) devices in Python.
and i was trying to control a BLE device that included notify and indicate properties in one characteristic, so there was a problem that only indicate is activated.

so when i checked the bleak source code, it was found that if indicate exists, activate it as indicate, and if not, check notify and activate it as notify, and start_notify works.

the following is the relevant source code and link.

https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/bleak/backends/winrt/client.py

```
    async def start_notify(
        self,
        char_specifier: Union[BleakGATTCharacteristic, int, str, uuid.UUID],
        callback: Callable[[int, bytearray], None],
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        ...
        ...
        characteristic_obj = characteristic.obj
        if (
            characteristic_obj.characteristic_properties
            & GattCharacteristicProperties.INDICATE
        ):
            cccd = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.INDICATE
        elif (
            characteristic_obj.characteristic_properties
            & GattCharacteristicProperties.NOTIFY
        ):
            cccd = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.NOTIFY
        else:
            cccd = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.NONE

        fcn = _notification_wrapper(bleak_callback, asyncio.get_event_loop())
        event_handler_token = characteristic_obj.add_value_changed(fcn)
        self._notification_callbacks[characteristic.handle] = event_handler_token
        status = await characteristic_obj.write_client_characteristic_configuration_descriptor_async(
            cccd
        )
```

what is the best way to deal with it in this case?
so i implemented the code below to use "notify", but it doesn't look good.

```
async with BleakClient(address, timeout=5.0) as client:
    client.set_disconnected_callback(on_disconnect)                        
    services = await client.get_services()        
    for service in services:
        for characteristic in service.characteristics:
            if characteristic.uuid == read_write_charcteristic_uuid:  
                if 'notify' in characteristic.properties:
                    # if "indicate" is exist remove it
                    if 'indicate' in characteristic.properties:
                        characteristic.properties.remove('indicate')
                    # then "notify" becomes active.
                    await client.start_notify(notify_charcteristic, callback)
```

thank you